# Cannot understand notation

Tags: jar

I'm trying to run a Jar file on ubuntu 14.04. I've already installed  OpenJDK Java 6 and 7 Runtime and turned the jar file to be executable. I double click on the file but nothing seems to happen!

I also read the given directions below but I cannot understand what to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar Hypatia_7.4_Masterclass.jar
```

Should I write something on the terminal in order to run the file?

Comment: Do you mean that you ran the lines above, or did you put it in a file and run it?  Do you get any messages if you run `java -jar Hypatia_7.4_Masterclass.jar` on the command line?

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me. When I type  *** java -jar filename.jar *** on the command line I get the following message:   ** Unable to access jarfile filename.jar **

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> java -jar Hypatia_7.4_Masterclass.jar
> ```

This "set of instructions" you have is just bash script. If you're unfamiliar with shell scripting, here is a quick intro on [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting#What_is_shell_scripting.3F), but you don't need to worry about that to run your file.

All you have to do to run a .jar file is open a terminal and type `java -jar WhateverYourFileNameIs.jar`.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me. Once I type *** java -jar filename.jar *** on the command line I get the following message: ** Unable to access jarfile filename.jar **

Comment: When you are typing that into your console, have you navigated to the directory that contains the file you want to use? Usually if you start a terminal in Ubuntu it starts at your home folder, which is `~` for short. You can change your directory with the cd command. Alternatively, you can navigate to the directory in nautilus, right click on the background of the directory window, and select `Open in terminal`.

Comment: I managed to navigate to the directory that contained the file (!!!) but I get the following message :

Comment: I managed to navigate to the file's directory but I got the following message:

AtlantisJava version (SVN tag): AtlantisJava (SVN tag n/a)
Command line arguments:

INFO  2017-03-08 01:31:33,730  Logging to console (System.out) initialised
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
 at atlantis.utils.AUtilities.getFileAsImageIcon(AUtilities.java:339)
 at atlantis.gui.AStartupWindow.<init>(AStartupWindow.java:42)
 at atlantis.Atlantis.initAtlantis(Atlantis.java:402)
 at atlantis.Atlantis.main(Atlantis.java:901)